# Set core file size limit permanently

Tags: ulimit, resource-limiting, systemd-coredump

I am trying to allow all core dump files to take up to 10 GB on  22.04.2. Permanently. For all users. I believe the unit is 1KB-blocks. I know I can do `ulimit -c 10000` to set the limit for at least the given bash session. But I want it to always be 10 GB rather than the default of 0.

I have tried setting

```
*               soft    core            10000
*               hard    core            10000
```

in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

And

```
DefaultLimitCORE=10000
```

in `/etc/systemd/user.conf` and `/etc/systemd/system.conf`.

And have rebooted. But I always just get

```
# ulimit -c
0
```

Any ideas here? Thank you!